# CMake, edit fields visible with ccmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have searched online, but I haven't found anything because I don't know the correct keywords to express what I need.

I am in a the `build/` directory of a repository; if I run `ccmake ../` there is a list of "flags (?)" that I can turn ON/OFF in order to decide what stuff do I want to build. If I want to turn ON the BUILD_THIS:

```
ccmake ../
#press Enter to turn that flag ON
#press c to configure
#press e to exit
#press g to generate
cmake --build . --target install
```

I am in a computer that has only cmake, and no ccmake. How can I do the same with cmake? Turn ON/OFF these flags, configure, and generate?

Comment: `cmake -DBUILD_THIS=ON ../`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ccmake` is a graphical interface around cmake. With access to command line, you just type what options you want to set. You do not need to have ccmake.

```
cmake ../ -DBUILD_THIS=ON
```